# htaccess redirection causing 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect users from this link:

```
http://mySite/myFolder/user/userName
```

or this one

```
http://www.mySite/myFolder/user/userName
```

to this :

```
http://mySite/myFolder/members/userName
```

Using `.htaccess` so I added this line to the end of the file :

```
Redirect 301 %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/fikra/user/$1 %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/members/$1
```

I had 500 error on the server .

I tried also this :

```
Redirect 301 ^(.*)/myFolder/user/$1 http://mySite/members/$1
```

And it doesn't work.

I would like to fix this error :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
RewriteRule myFolder/user/(.*) http://example.com/members/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain L and NC ?

Comment: They are flags ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)). `L` causes this round of rewriting to stop (often done for optimization and stopping multiple rules doing conflicting things). `NC` makes the rule case-insensitive.

Comment: Start the match pattern with ^ (RewriteRule ^myFolder...) so that a URI such as /glotz/myFolder/... won't match. Unless it is important to specifically have the non-www form of your domain used, you could drop the `http://example.com` part. Use R=301 only if you want to tell visitors (and search engines) that they've been redirected and they should remember the new address. Note that R=302 is the default if you give `http://example.com`.